# Making a Javascript "Load more" pagination without JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I'm making a mobile version of my website and I want to add a "Load more" button at the bottom. I found many ways to do this, but they all require JQuery or MooTools. Since it's a mobile site, I don't want to load a huge script. How can I do it without JQuery?

Comment: I'd prolly wanna test the performance to see if it really mattered, before making the decision to avoid jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do it using raw JS.  For example instead of using $.ajax() you could use XMLHTTPRequest().

jQuery also has a mobile version which you might be interested in. [Link](http://jquerymobile.com/)